# Reproducir archivo de audio completo con python-vlc

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un reproductor de música en Python y ocupo `libvlc` mediante [`python-vlc`](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/), sin embargo no se como reproducir un audio hasta que se termine, ya que si quito la función `time.sleep` no reproduce el audio.

Este es mi código:

```
import vlc
import time

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new('1.mp3')
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque la reproducción se realiza de forma asíncrona, debes mantener la ejecución del proceso que crea la instancia del reproductor mientras la reproducción no termine.

Tu problema es que después del `sleep` el proceso Python no tiene más que hacer y termina, terminando también la reproducción. Tienes varias opciones, mi preferida por flexibilidad es usar [`vlc.MediaListPlayer.get_state`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaListPlayer-class.html#get_state) que te permite conocer el estado del reproductor en cualquier momento, retorna una instancia de [`vlc.State`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.State-class.html) y puedes comparar mediante:

> ```
> ╔════════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
> ║ ESTADO         ║ VALOR                    ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Buffering      ║ vlc.State.Buffering      ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Error          ║ vlc.State.Error          ║     
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Ended          ║ vlc.State.Ended          ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ NothingSpecial ║ vlc.State.NothingSpecial ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Opening        ║ vlc.State.Opening        ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Paused         ║ vlc.State.Paused         ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Playing        ║ vlc.State.Playing        ║
> ╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
> ║ Stopped        ║ vlc.State.Stopped        ║
> ╚════════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
> ```

Simplificando puedes hacer esto:

```
import vlc
import time

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new('1.mp3')
player.set_media(media)
player.play()

while player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
    time.sleep(1)  # Solo para evitar un uso innecesario de CPU
```

Otra opción es usar [`vlc.MediaListPlayer.is_playing`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaListPlayer-class.html#is_playing) que retorna `1/True` si el reproductor está reproduciendo algo y `0/False` en caso contrario:

```
import vlc
import time

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new('1.mp3')
player.set_media(media)
player.play()

time.sleep(5)  # Dar un tiempo prudencial para que la reproducción inicie.
while player.is_playing():
    time.sleep(1)
```

La idea es que el proceso no termine antes de terminar la reproducción, el medio va a depender de lo que quieras hacer y de como lo implementes. Por ejemplo, si vas a crear un interfaz gráfica y la instancia del reproductor la haces en el mismo proceso que la GUI no vas a necesitar nada de esto, ya que el proceso no termina hasta que cierres la interfaz gracias al mainloop de ésta.